# Migrating to Liferay 7 from liferay 6.1.2

Tags: liferay

I have been reading the liferay documentation about migrating from liferay 6 to liferay 7 (https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/from-liferay-6-to-liferay-7).
I have a basic liferay 6.1.2 application bundle with tomcat that contains a few portlets and all I need is to make it work the same way, without using any new feature (OSGI and all) with liferay 7.

Do you know where I could find a list of new configuration files and a list of the ones that have been deleted?

Is there a place where I can find the new dependencies required by liferay 7 for each of my portlets?

I used the liferay tool to generate the new theme so that's a start...

Any links or advices would be appreciated,

Thanks

EDIT :

I can start liferay 7 with the portlet inside the /deploy. I get no errors, only info like "portlet1.war does not have a WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.xml or liferay-plugin-package.properties."
The localhost_host_access.log show a few 404 but not as an error...
I really dont know how to proceed to have information (errors, logs,....) to make this work : my portal is still empty.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the upgrade procedure (read through the link you've provided) and it should be able to

- upgrade your database
- upgrade parts of your code

If you are using [Liferay IDE or Developer Studio](https://web.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide) there is code migration wizard. It will not solve all issues but will examine your code and advise you how to change things it can not change itself. [This recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm-EFz7wew8) in an year old but it will give you an idea of what IDE does (probably more by now). It uses a database of breaking changes, most of which is published [here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/breaking-changes) so you can check what is relevant to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to use the code upgrade tool but I don't understand how it's working from the documentation (https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adapting-to-liferay-7s-api-with-the-code-upgrade-tool). I downloaded the IDE and the SDK but what does that sentence mean "Then, either move your plugin into the Liferay Portal CE 7.0 Plugins SDK or unzip the Liferay Portal CE 7.0 Plugins SDK on top of your existing Plugins SDK. This upgrades it to the latest version. " ?

Comment: This is relevant to plugins that were build with Lieray SDK. Each Liferay version has corresponding SDK that is aware of the Liferay APIs in this particular version. So if you have your portlet's code in say 6.2 SDK you need to either copy it to 7.0 SDK or upgrade your 6.2 SDK to 7.0. Once you have your code in 7.0 SDK the upgrade wizard will examine it and suggest how to upgrade it.

Comment: Thank you. So we can't use the upgrade tool for portlet that were develop without liferay SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you do that. First migrates from 6.1 to 6.2 and after 6.2 to 7 or you can redo the entire portal, from Liferay we do not recommend making such low migrations. I recommend you look at the community and OSGI ...